# AWS Lambda Execution result: failed

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've written a lambda function in the AWS Lambda GUI. The program I've written will send me an email, the program appears to work but there is error in my logs and I cannot even begin to understand those errors. I like to seek help on how to resolve the error.

This is the error I've gotten:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2020-04-27T07:22:08.185Z b6ec9468-75c2-4e39-aeeb-bd0085758fb8 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
}
```

This is the log output

```
START RequestId: b6ec9468-75c2-4e39-aeeb-bd0085758fb8 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: b6ec9468-75c2-4e39-aeeb-bd0085758fb8
REPORT RequestId: b6ec9468-75c2-4e39-aeeb-bd0085758fb8  Duration: 3003.16 ms    Billed Duration: 3000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 50 MB  Init Duration: 122.21 ms    
2020-04-27T07:22:08.185Z b6ec9468-75c2-4e39-aeeb-bd0085758fb8 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds
```

And my code is below (mail-demo.py)

```
import os
import smtplib

def main(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    EMAIL_ADDRESS = os.environ['EMAIL_ADD']
    EMAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ['EMAIL_PWD']

    with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as smtp:
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.starttls()
        smtp.ehlo()

        smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)

        subject = 'Wassup!'
        body = 'Testing some lambda function at don\'t know what time'

        msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'

        smtp.sendmail(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_ADDRESS, msg)

    return 'email sent success'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to increase your functions execution [timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-console.html):

> Timeout – The amount of time that Lambda allows a function to run before stopping it. **The default is 3 seconds**. The maximum allowed value is 900 seconds.